# Getting the name of an app from a Bundle ID on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use this code:

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:item] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
```

To get the name of an app from its Bundle Identifier, however for all non-stock apps this method is returning nil. I have tried to look for ways to solve this to no avail.  How can I get the name of an app from the bundle ID in iOS 8?

EDIT: To clarify, I want to use this for apps other than my own.

Comment: i threw up an answer.  but do you mean you want to get the name of another app besides the app you are running the code in?

Comment: @myte Sorry if it was unclear! I want to get the name of apps besides my own.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
```

Or if you want to be a bit more correct, reference `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]`

However, instead of accessing the **CFBundleExecutable** key, you are better off accessing the **CFBundleName** key instead, which is the name under your apps icon.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

Comment: you dont need bundle identifier for app name . Just get it directly

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:bundleIdentifier];
NSString *appName = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
NSLog(@"%@", appName);
```